# Google Calendar API PHP Installation

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I have been trying to get the Google Calendar API working with PHP, I even contacted my host (1and1) to figure things out, nothing is working

I've followed the examples on the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php),  tried to run it just by going to the page and it gave me an error to run it in command line.  So I logged into my SSH, navigated to the file and ran the command `php5.4 CRON-temp.php`.  Now, I get the same error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This application must be
run on the command line.' in /homepages/41/d159654153/htdocs/mysite
/admin/php/CRON-temp.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in <b>/homepages/41/d159654153/htdocs/mysite/
admin/php/CRON-temp.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

So, I've run it in the command line, but it still tells me to run it there.  The code throwing the error comes from this:

```
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
```

I've been held up here...  I've sent the code to a friend to try out and he gets a link to return where I'm supposed to go authorize this, but I'm not able to see any of that.

The tech person at 1and1 said

> Now, if you will look at the error, the error changes from "parse error" to "Uncaught exception 'Exception". It appears that this application will run in server environment and not on a shared hosting. This is a limitation on the package that you have. You might need to go to a server package for this API to run.

Is this really the case?  Do I really need to switch over to server hosting?  Is there a way around this?

All I want to do is have a 2 way sync between Google Calendar and a mySQL server.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Google code and instructions i.e. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php 
first you try to run this using `cmd`.

Go to `start` type `cmd` and then black screen will appear type here as:
`php yourfilename.php`, then it will provide you a url and ask for verification code you just visit the said url and allow the Google and get key and enter the said key in cmd.

Your code is ready to use. Now comment the same code which is restricting for cli i.e:

```
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your post from a project that I'm currently working on. You can run quickstart.php from the command line which then gives you a link to paste into your browser to authorize access.

Once you have authorized access, you can run the script in the command line again and it displays upcoming events.

There is no browser output - that is what I am looking for.

I hope this helps.